# jqgrid select input width

Tags: jqgrid

how can control the width of a select input type?
this is my code:

```
{name:'code',index:'code', width:60, sorttype:"int" ,
 editable:true, edittype:"select",editoptions: {value:"1:11;2:22"}
```

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert in the list of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions) `dataInit` function which set the width which you need. For example

```
editoptions: {
    value:"1:11;2:22",
    dataInit: function(elem) {
        $(elem).width(50);  // set the width which you need
    }
}
```